# How does the Sun generate its periodically reversing large-scale magnetic field?

Tags: star, the-sun, magnetic-field

How does the Sun generate its periodically reversing large-scale magnetic field?

Comment: This is an entire research field!

Comment: I agree with Rob, see for example, this [NASA article](http://www.nasa.gov/feature/goddard/2016/understanding-the-magnetic-sun).